# Javascript List-like Datastructure

Tags: javascript, data-structures

What data structure is this in JavaScript? Is seems like a list, but then why does it have a curly brace and not the standard "[]"?

```
    var states = {
      "California": {
       "Monterey": ["Salinas", "Gonzales"],
       "Alameda": ["Oakland", "Berkeley"]
       },
    "Oregon": {
      "Douglas": ["Roseburg", "Winston"],
      "Jackson": ["Medford", "Jacksonville"]
      }
    }
```

I am interested in creating some sort of array that has a structure like this:

Colors: Red, Green, Blue, Orange, Yellow

Food: Bananas, Oranges

People: Me, You, Us, Them

...

Does something like this exist in Javascript?

Thanks!

Comment: It's an object with nested objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the main tools available to you in Javascript is [objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer). They're hash maps, or dictionaries, or key-value pairs, or whatever you'd like to call them. The key is a string (or [symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Symbol)) and the value can be anything, including other objects.

To create the kind of relationship you're talking about, you could write something like this:

```
var obj = {
  colors: ['red', 'green', 'blue'],
  food: ['bananas', 'oranges'],
  people: ['me', 'you', 'us']
};
console.log(obj.colors);
console.log(obj.food);
console.log(obj.people);
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear information and links, Kabali's answer is closer to what I was looking for since its easier to make dynamic values with. I appreciate the help  :)

Comment: @noc_coder For what it's worth, Kabali's way of adding new properties to an object is unconventional and not recommended. Doing `obj.Colors = innerArray` is the same thing as `obj['Colors'] = innerArray`.

Answer (score 2):

Answer of first part of your question is this is an `object`. We can declare `object` like that. for practice [Object](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp) you can use this link.For the second part  There are many way by which you can add elements to an object. In my example I declare an object an then add attributes in the object.

```js
var obj = {};
  obj.Colors = ['Red', 'Green', 'Blue','Orange', 'Yellow'],
  obj.Food = ['Bananas', 'Oranges'],
  obj.People = ['Me', 'You', 'Us','Them'] 
  console.log(obj.Colors);
  console.log(obj.Food);
  console.log(obj.People);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an object. It can have as many nested data types as you like

Comment: But what if my properties are uneven and unrelated as in the example I gave above??

Comment: That's ok! JS objects have few rules - try it out!

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>   
var arrayObj = [];

var obj = {};
var innerArray = ['Red', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Orange', 'Yellow'];
var secondArray = ['Me', 'You', 'Us', 'Them'];
obj['Colors'] = innerArray;
obj['People'] = secondArray ;
arrayObj .push(obj);
</script>
```

You can do like this

Answer (score 0):

Should be an object with nested objects array.
Somewhat similar with this.

```
var countries = {
    "USA" : {
         "Alabama" : {
                "Birmingham" : 371,
                "Montgomery" : 8771 },
         "Alaska" : {
                "Anchorage" : 9918,
                "Nome" : 8171 },
          "Wyoming"  : {
                "Casper" : 718,
                "Cody" : 888 }
        },
    "Canada" : [ 
        "Alberta" : {
              "Calgary" : "Z871" },
        "British Columbia" {
              "Vancouver" : "B88C",
              "Victoria" : "C99A" },
      ...
};
```